# AUTOCAD/IJCAD UNDO履歴のクリア

Tags: ijcad

- 現在、複数の図面を更新する機能を開発しています。
- 図面をまたぐので`CommandFlags.Session`を指定しています。

更新した情報を戻せないように`UNDO`履歴をクリアしようとしているのですが、`CommandFlags.Session`の機能では、`Document.Editor.Command`も`acedCmd`も正常に動作しないようです。

そこで、`Document.SendStringToExecute`に引数`"UNDO C N UNDO A "`を指定して、`UNDO`を無効にして、再度有効にすることで`UNDO`履歴をクリアしています。

しかし、このやり方では、`CMDECHO`をオフにしてもコマンドラインに処理内容が表示されます。
また、コマンドラインの履歴に`UNDO`が残っています。

以下の2点に対応する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

1. コマンドラインに処理内容を表示しないようにする方法
2. コマンドラインの履歴に`UNDO`が残らないようにする方法
   (`CommandFlags.NoHistory`と同様の効果が得られる方法)

`SendStringToExecute`以外の方法でもかまいませんので、ご教授の程よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

AutoCADでは以下の方法によるコマンド呼び出して、CMDECHOがオフの状態であればコマンドラインにUNDOコマンドの履歴が残りません。

```
[CommandMethod("TESTCMD", CommandFlags.Session)]
public void TestCommand()
{
    UndoClear();
}

private static async void UndoClear()
{
    var docs = Application.DocumentManager;
    var doc = docs.MdiActiveDocument;
    var ed = doc.Editor;
    try
    {
        await docs.ExecuteInCommandContextAsync(
          async (obj) => { await ed.CommandAsync("Undo", "C", "N", "UNDO", "A"); },
          null
        );
    }
    catch { }
}
```

IJCADでは ExecuteInCommandContextAsync が実装されていないので、COMとLISPを使用してUNDOコマンドを呼び出します。

```
[CommandMethod("TESTCMD", CommandFlags.Session)]
public void TestCommand(){
    var acadDoc = ((dynamic)Application.AcadApplication).ActiveDocument;
    acadDoc.SendCommand("(command \"UNDO\" \"C\" \"N\" \"UNDO\" \"A\")\n");
}
```

ただしこの方法ではコマンドラインに、(command "UNDO" "C" "N" "UNDO" "A")とnilが残ってしまいます。